# Why doesn't the "Press This" bookmarklet work on GitHub?

Tags: github

This is a mystery to me. The "Press This" bookmarklet works well for me, everywhere except when I try to press one of my GitHub repositories.

It doesn't just fail to grab anything, the window fails to open altogether.

Does anyone else experience this? Is this a known / documented bug? Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the Content Security Policy (CSP) that [Github rolled out](https://github.com/blog/1477-content-security-policy) in April 2013. CSP *shouldn't* cause problems with bookmarklets, but it does in practice.

The issue isn't specific to PressThis either. It causes problems with bookmarklets from [Pinboard](https://twitter.com/pinboard/status/329752745601015809), Pocket and Instapaper.

In Chrome you can hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the developer tools and see the error:

[image: Error message in the Chrome developer tools console after attempting to use the Pocket bookmarklet on a Github page]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But grrrr! Is there any way around this, or do we just have to not press when we update our repos on GitHub?

Comment: There are workarounds, but none are ideal. You can disable CSP in your browser, or rewrite the bookmarklet to have all the code instead of loading a remote script.